# Does msp430 UCSWRST = 1 also reset the bit clock genetator?

Tags: spi, msp430

Chapter SPI.3.1 says:

"The USCI is reset by a PUC or by the UCSWRST bit. After a PUC, the UCSWRST bit is automatically set,
keeping the USCI in a reset condition. When set, the UCSWRST bit resets the UCxRXIE, UCxTXIE,
UCxRXIFG, UCOE, and UCFE bits and sets the UCxTXIFG flag. Clearing UCSWRST releases the USCI
for operation."

It is silent about what happens to the bit clock generator.  This has some impact with low baud rates (high prescaler values.)

Is the SPI timing deterministic due to RxIFG stopping the bit clock generator input or does it only stop the bit clock generator output?

If it is not deterministic, any suggestions how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it depends if you are in master or in slave mode.

> 16.3.5 SPI Enable
>
> When the USCI module is enabled by clearing the UCSWRST bit it is ready to receive and transmit. In
> master mode the bit clock generator is ready, but is not clocked nor producing any clocks. In slave mode
> the bit clock generator is disabled and the clock is provided by the master.
> A transmit or receive operation is indicated by UCBUSY = 1.
> A PUC or set UCSWRST bit disables the USCI immediately and any active transfer is terminated.

Comment: Your answer implies that the bit clock is reset and the divider will start counting from the same value.